# Best Practice. Script task or Truncate Table Reread Flat File

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flat-file, script-task

I am wondering which one is the best practice out of these two options:

1. Reverse read text file (.txt) and take the line where the date > max(date) in table by using script task in ssis
2. re-Read Flat File (.txt) every time SSIS runs, truncate and reinsert everything in the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before asking your first question, it is recommended to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com) to learn more about asking good questions, accepting answers and other website rules. Also to get your the *"informed"* badge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow these steps:

1. Add an Execute SQL Task that Get The MaxDate and Store it into a Date Variable
2. Add a DataFlow Task
3. In the DataFlow Task add a Flat File Source, Conditional Split, OLEDB Destination
4. In the Conditional Split, filter only rows Where `[Date] > @[User::Date Variable]`

This approach is better then the two approaches you mentioned

**Additional Information**

- [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)
- [Simple SSIS: Importing Data from Flat Text Files](http://www.ingenioussql.com/2014/12/11/simple-ssis-importing-data-from-flat-text-files/)
- [Result Sets in the Execute SQL Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280492(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: Great, Never thought of that way! Thanks Hadi :)